# Can you always access suitably aligned buffer containing structure data in C?

Tags: c, c11

I have data of a structure type in C:

```
typedef struct {
  type0 field0;
  type1 field1;
} foo_struct;

foo_struct foo;
```

Now let's say I have a buffer allocated in some fashion in virtual memory, of size `sizeof(foo_struct)`

```
char *buf = <some allocation method>
```

Then I copy the data from `foo` to `buf`, for example by `memcpy`.

Then I want to access the fields in `buf` like so:

```
((foo_struct *)buf)->fieldn
```

Is this guaranteed (by the C11 standard) to always work?

People in another question (on a different main topic)
, seem to be saying, yes this is guaranteed to work, especially provided that `buf` is well-aligned, like, on a page boundary.

Yes it is practically assured.  But I think, no matter how well it is "aligned", page boundary, or what not, there is no 100% guarantee by the standard.  Is there?

Comment: Without additional information, this cannot be guaranteed. It can even invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: The references for malloc (since this is C) I find state that "If allocation succeeds, returns a pointer to the lowest (first) byte in the allocated memory block that is suitably aligned for any scalar type".

Comment: Actually, it's in the standard, sort of. The standard states that `malloc` should return an aligned memory that fits any type. Also, struct padding is semi-required (you can waive it away) so that an array of the same struct wouldn't break memory alignment. In essence, unless your type's memory requirement is bigger then the machine's alignment (i.e. `SSE` extensions), you should be fine.

Comment: @rcgldr it need not be `malloc`, could be, for example, the result of `mmap`, that's why I did not specify the allocation method.

Comment: C11 standard paragraph 7.22.3.4 states "The `malloc` function allocates space for an object whose size is specified by size and
whose value is indeterminate.". Implementations vary. Ergo C11 standard hands out no guarantees for even a basic `malloc` operation

Comment: There is posix_memalign() if you need to allocate a datastructure with types that have a larger alignment requirement than those of C's builtin types.

Comment: @Steen That's not the implication of that statement in C11 at all. 7.22.3.1 already says that the returned pointer is suitable aligned for anytihng.

Comment: @Steen That statement is talking in particular about indeterminate arrays within structs.

Comment: Every reference I could find, are operating system/platform specific... but I agree, it's more an assumption.

Comment: [link](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~zbyszek/ipp/c11standard.pdf) 7.22.3 Memory management functions says it all... You can be sure

Comment: @Myst Detail about "aligned memory that fits any type" Spec says " suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of _object_" has an odd exception with a pointer to a _function_, which is not a pointer to an object. Allocating a pointer to a function is odd anyways.   IAC, `*alloc()` does provide well aligned pointers.

Comment: Thank you all, I appreciate your comments and answers.  But, nobody really addressed the question I posted, which does not assume `malloc` or anything about the particular allocation method.

Comment: @G.Sliepen `posix_memalign` is not mandatory on all conforming implementations.

Answer (score 7):

> Can you always access suitably aligned buffer containing structure
>   data in C?

If the buffer's in dynamic memory, then yes.

```
char *buf = malloc(1000000);
if(buf)
   ((foo_struct *)buf)->fieldn
```

is essentially like

```
foo_struct *buf = malloc(1000000);
if(buf)
    buf->fieldn
```

This is guaranteed to work.

If the buffer is statically allocated or automatic, then no.
Aliasing rules ([6.5p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7)) prevent you from doing:

```
/*static*/ _Alignas(foo_struct) char buf[100000000];
foo_struct* foo_p = &buf;
if(foo_p)
    foo_p->fieldn
```

even when the alignment of the buffer is sufficient.

(Note: 1 followed by many 0 == large enough)

Comment: I don't quite understand why the second one wouldn't work. It does on my computer. Am I missing something?

Comment: @gowrath, because the effective type of an object is fixed if it has a type via its allocation. You can only change the effective type for objects that don't have an initial type.

Comment: @JensGustedt  I must have misunderstood. I though the answer was saying the compiler will literally not let you do that.

Comment: @gowrath `char buf[100000000];` is `char` aligned.  `foo_struct* foo_p = &buf;` obliges `foo_p` to receive a suitable aligned value for pointing to `foo_struct`.  `foo_struct* foo_p = &buf;` is UB.  `foo_p->fieldn` is UB.

Comment: `_Alignas(foo_struct) char buf[100000000];` is a good improvement to create a buffer align-able to `foo_struct`.  Could use C11 `_Alignas(max_align_t) any_object_type buf[100000000];` and cover all cases.

Comment: @chux That doesn't work because you can't change effective type of objects without allocated storage duration.

Answer (score 6):

It kind of depends on what `<some allocation method>` is. Here is what the [standard](http://students.mimuw.edu.pl/~zbyszek/ipp/c11standard.pdf) [7.22.3] says about malloc :

> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is suitably aligned so that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a fundamental alignment requirement and then used to access such an object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the space is explicitly deallocated).

So according to the standard, you can do what you're asking when using malloc. Most other well written memory allocators should satisfy this requirement as well.

Answer (score 1):

The aliasing rules of C89 were historically interpreted as merely identifying the minimum cases where all conforming implementations would be required to recognize aliasing, which they in turn limited to cases which would be useful on all implementations.  It was obvious to everyone involved at the time that other forms of aliasing are useful on many platforms, and that quality implementations should recognize such forms when practical.

While C99 and C11 have pretended to describe more fully the cases where quality implementations should recognize aliasing, the authors have never made any real effort to handle some cases that should be easy to handle, and are absolutely vital in system programming.  Since even pessimistic handling of such cases would generally have only a small impact on performance, compiler writers used to approach such things with caution, and the notion that such code should work used to be viewed as common sense.

Memory management with approaches like you describe (rather than malloc/free) will work reliably if compiler writers use some common sense, since most useful aliasing optimizations (as opposed to code-breaking aliasing "optimizations") aren't going to require moving object accesses across pointer type conversions.  Unfortunately, for whatever reason, it isn't fashionable for compilers to include a "common-sense" aliasing mode.

While it would be rather useless to specify alignment of objects' storage if one can't use that storage in a way that benefits from it, the Standard doesn't mandate that compilers allow such use of the storage underlying objects declared with alignment directives.  Because it is fashionable for compiler writers to pay more attention to what the Standard doesn't require than to what usefulness would require, the only way to be assured with many compilers that any kind of custom memory-management code will work will be to either use compiler-specific directives or else to disable aliasing optimizations altogether.